# Combobox inside DataGrid not displaying SelectedItem

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, datagrid, combobox, selecteditem

I'm trying to learn Silverlight with MVVM pattern. I've stumbled across a problem that's puzzling me for quite few hours

I've a `Combobox` inside a `Datagrid`. When the combobox is opened, the item corresponding to the `SelectedItem` of `Datagrid` isn't being selected in the Combobox options.

This is my  **Model**

```
public class Address : ViewModelBase
{
    private string streetName;
    public string StreetName{...}

    private City city;
    public City City {...}
}
public class City : ViewModelBase
{
    private string cityName;
    public string CityName{...}

    private string code;
    public string Code{...}
}
```

This is my **ViewModel**

```
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    #region Fields        
    private Address selectedAddress;        
    #endregion

    #region Properties       
    public ObservableCollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<City> Cities { get; set; }        
    public Address SelectedAddress {...}       
    #endregion

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        InitializeProperties();
    }

    #region Methods
    private void InitializeProperties()
    {
        InitializeAddresses(...);
        InitializeCities(...);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

And my **XAML**

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Addresses, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedAddress, Mode=TwoWay}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="25" ColumnWidth="*">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="Street Name"
            Binding="{Binding Path=StreetName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="City Name">
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=City.CityName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>                                        
                    <ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="CityName"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding
                       RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=sdk:DataGrid},
                       Path=DataContext.Cities, Mode=OneWay}" 
                      SelectedItem="{Binding Path=City, Mode=TwoWay,
                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Header="City Code"
            Binding="{Binding Path=City.Code, Mode=TwoWay}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Then if I make a selection from `combobox` dropdown menu, next time I open the combobx it will be selected.

[When the combobox is opened](http://i.imgur.com/gTlhdkf)

[What I'm looking for when the combobox is opend](http://i.imgur.com/LUsBFvj)

Also when the user selects an item from `combobox`, it should be binded to the `Datagrid`'s `SelectedItem`'s `City` property.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions or links to a solution.

Comment: Is `ViewModelBase` derived from `UIElement` or `FrameworkElement`? (which is both not advisable)

Comment: @Martin `ViewModelBase` is a class implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface.

Comment: `Binding Path=City` ... where is this `City` property defined? I'd expect to see it in your ViewModel, but only see the `Cities` collection there.

Comment: `Binding Path=City` points to the `SelectedAddress.City`. I believe `ComboBox`'s `DataContext` is `DataGrid`'s `SelectedItem` property. I'm not sure on this though.

Comment: @Ash: no, not exactly, each row has its own DataContext (and therefore each ComboBox has its own DataContext): you set ItemsSource on the DataGrid, and that means that for each item in the source a row is created. The ComboBox is inside a Template, and that template gets instantiated for each row, and the item that caused the row creation is used as the DataContext.

Comment: only if you are clicking on a row and opening the ComboBox, the clicked row's item is at the same time the SelectedItem. But that still means the comboBox is bound to just an item, and not necessarily to the SelectedItem. Hope that clarifies.

Comment: @Martin yeah that cleared it up for me. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Edit]
I have an idea what might be going wrong...
How do you initialize the list of available cities and the addresses?
Because **if you are not using the same instances** you created to populate the available city list for initializing the addresses, then the `SelectedItem` you have bound **is not found in the `ItemsSource`** (think: object identity).

so you should do it like this:

```
var cities = InitializeCities(...);
InitializeAddresses( cities );
...
private void InitializeAddresses(... cities)
{
    ...
    var address = new Address {City = cities[42] };
```

[Original Post]
Try removing the explicit `UpdateSource` trigger, it is not needed for the `ComboBox` and may interfere in a way.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding Path=City, Mode=TwoWay}"
```

Comment: @Ash : ok, had an idea what might cause your problem, have a look at my updated post.

Comment: You are right, that is the problem. I wasn't using the `Cities`collection to initialize `Address`. I was creating a new instance of a `City` object in every `Address` object for the `Addresses` Collection. Made me look more into Object Identity. Thanks a million.